# Bug in window list in gnome-session-flashback

Tags: compiz, gnome-panel, gnome-flashback

When I right click on a window in the bottom gnome panel, the menu that pops up cover gnome panel. How can I change that in order to have the pop- up menu shows and covers the gnome-panel itself. It is very annoying since when I right click to do something on that window the mouse can close it right away. I only get this bug under compiz. In metacity things are okay.

Can you give me suggestions on how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: 1. Screenshot is needed (`gnome-screenshot -d 3`). 2. If it is bug you should report it to launchpad.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCUjQ.png

Comment: I see the same behavior on MATE DE. If I understand correctly it is expected, not a bug. Right-clicking on the panel opens menu it place you clicked. But clicking on window name opens menu above it.